# How to make a wheel recharge the battery as it decelerates?

Tags: motor, battery-charging

From my knowledge, a motor acts as a generator and has voltage in its inputs if the shaft is spun.

If I use a battery to spin a motor+wheel to high rpm and then turn it off (with a switch), how can I regenerate the battery? The wheel has a lot of energy which can be used to recharge some of the energy lost by battery to accelerate it.

Comment: So after you turn it off you don't mind the wheel will stop very quickly?

Comment: In a basic permanent magnet DC motor, a double pole double throw switch effectively reversing the direction of current would send energy in the reverse direction. The trick would be managing the voltage/current so that you get the right amount of braking/recharging happening.

Comment: Yes, I don't mind. I plan to turn on the motor again after 2-3 minutes and I suspect the wheel would decelerate to 0 by then due to friction.

Comment: Regenerative braking or KERS systems is a very broad subject and actually quite tricky to get right. Lots of information online. Voting to close.

Comment: @horta I'm planning to build a pitching machine where the motor is active while the balls are pitched (1 ball every 10 seconds for 12 balls, followed by 3 minutes of rest). So, braking force isn't a concern as long as excessive current doesn't harm the battery.

Comment: For something like that, switching in a boost convertor to pull current from the motor as it slows with a charge controller to prevent damage to the batteries, and something to monitor and control all that would not be that bad. EIther that or dump the energy in a super-capacitor bank and pull it back out when needed.

Comment: What's the motor, what is the battery? Voltages and currents count.

Comment: Motor is rated at 24V 250W (rated current draw of 14 amp). Battery will be 2 12V car batteries in series.

Comment: @horta just flipping the motor around is fine if you want to use the battery energy to brake the rotation. It will not however extract the energy.

Comment: FYI it's good practice when responding to a comment to add the user's name preceded by the ampersand as in @Trevor. That way the person you are replying to gets a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK you need some form of energy harvester.

That is, when you turn off the motor the back-emf will still be present in the motor and it will act as a generator driven by the inertia of your mechanics, which, for a ball-thrower I am assuming is pretty high and it spins on for some time after you cut the power.

As such you need an energy harvester circuit. This is basically a switch mode boost convertor that will "suck" current out of the motor and boost the voltage out up to greater than your battery voltage by a volt or two.

Since the back emf will fall as the motor slows down you need a booster that is capable of running down to small voltages so you can harvest the maximum amount of energy out it. Also, the booster needs to be current limited as you do not want to draw current out of the motor too fast or it may overheat.

There are numerous ready made boost convertors or harvesters out there though 24V ones may be fewer.

Here is a typical one, though it would be nicer if it went down below 5V.

[image]
[Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0757NRLD7)

If you want to design your own, Linear Technology etc. sell various DC-DC convertor ICs.

Note the harvester should only be turned on when the motor is off, also, although some automatically shut down when the voltage drops from the motor you may want to add your own supervision.

You may also want to consider augmenting your system by adding some large capacitors in parallel with the battery rather than charging the battery itself. Have those charge up above battery voltage, and then have your controller draw from those. That will be more efficient and increase the life of the battery.

Or if you are feeling adventurous something like this should work..

[image]
[image]